# Are microwave-generating devices (gyrotrons) in the ITER system phased to heat plasma?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, plasma-physics, microwaves

Provided electricity from grid is converted and supplies 24 gyrotrons, which generate electromagnetic waves, which in turn, will transfer their energy to the electrons of the ITER plasma to heat it up.

In general, electromagnetic waves are phased in the ITER system?

If phased

Electromagnetic waves are phased from the outset in the gyrotrons or phased in the exit of launchers?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by phased? Why do you think they would need to be in phase to heat the plasma?

Comment: microwave interference occurs? if their oscillations coincide or differ by a constant value, then the waves will be superimposed on each other. If the maximum coincides with the maximum and the minimum with a minimum, two waves amplify each other, and the amplitude of the oscillations doubles; if the maximum and minimum coincide, two waves cancel each other, forming a zero amplitude

Comment: all gyrotrons have similar operating frequency 170 GHz

Comment: You should consider a quick estimate of the absorption length in the plasma relative to the separation of the feed lines. You should also think about what the matching network (although not called out) does.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it is not very common to call two signal "*phased*", as you have done it (but different communities have different conventions). I guess what you mean is: "*are the signals from the various gyrotrons in phase?*"

The answer is: *no, they are not*.

Phased-locked gyrotrons (i.e. gyrotrons which are in phase) is something very new (or let's say, this came up again very recently) and there is no need for the ITER gyrotrons and/or transmission line design to use phased-locked gyrotrons.